# java JVM G1 Missing mark

Tags: jvm

From the book, G1 collector uses the primitive snapshot approach to solve the tri-color marker under-marking problem.
The G1 collector uses the TAMS pointer to solve the problem of storing newly created objects during concurrent collection, implicitly marking newly created objects as alive and not included in the collection.
What happens if an object that has been marked as black adds a reference to a white object that was created historically in the free state? (The black object has already been scanned by GC as a living object, the white object is historically created and is no longer in the GCRoots reference chain when it is scanned)

Comment: What book are you referring to?

Comment: When an application thread modifies an object, it must put that object (back) into the gray set.